# How can I find all the information needed for a postgresql connection string?

Tags: database, postgresql

I frequently run into the problem of trying to track down all the information such as the host, the user, the password, whether to use ssl, etc.  Is there an easy way to retrieve this information from the psql terminal?

```
host     = "localhost"
port     = 5432
user     = "postgres"
password = "password"
dbname   = "database"
```

I typically create databases with `createdb` but I don't know what user or password it is using.

Answer (score 5):

To find the host, port and user:

1. `psql` to open up terminal to postgres
2. `\c database` to connect to database
3. `\conninfo` to retrieve info about connection.

To reset the password:

1. `psql` to open terminal to postgres
2. `\password` to set new password (edited)

Comment: Thank you.  This is my local machine but that's very good to know.